# HTTP Error Code while trying to change an immutable object?

Tags: rest, http, error-handling

I have a quiz in which I can give an answer to a question over a restful API. The request will transmit the answer to the question over a PUT-Request to an URL like “/question/{id}/answer”. But each question can only be answered once. The answer can be queried over a get request but can never be changed again. What HTTP Error Code do I return when the client tries to change the immutable answer with a PUT request?

I tried this error codes:

- 405 Method Not Allowed: But in the first place a PUT is fine. But once the object is set a PUT is not allowed anymore. Is it OK if the list of allowed methods change over time?
- 409 Conflict: Would work, but the RfC says “his code is only allowed in situations where it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.” And here the client would not be able to resolve the conflict.
- 400 Bad Request: It is in general a bad request but not “due to malformed syntax.”
- So, is it a Server Error (5xx)? In case of a 500 Internal Server Error the RfC states that “The server encountered an unexpected condition”. But we expect the object to become immutable at some point.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it OK if the list of allowed methods change over time?

Yes.

> Allow header field in a 405 response containing a list of the target resource's currently supported methods. -- [RFC 7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.5)

Note: *currently* supported methods....